# What kind of power does Charlotte Cracker have?

Tags: one-piece

I know that Charlotte Cracker ate [Bisu Bisu no Mi](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Bisu_Bisu_no_Mi), that make him can create and manipulate biscuits.

But, at first of his appearance, he have a power to make nearby Homies to death just using his glare. As noted by Luffy, this power isn't haki.

So, what is this power?

I'm also read manga, and so far I don't get the explanation about this power, or maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 1):

It is implied in both in the anime and the manga that the [Soru Soru no Mi](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Soru_Soru_no_Mi)'s power involves fear...

During Big Mom's first shown tantrum, Mascato had lifespan taken partially because of fear.

It is explained in the anime that if the person subjected to the Soru Soru no Mi attack had any trace of fear he or she would have his or her life span taken away.

So, although it wasn't explicitly stated in the manga or anime, Cracker probably did a power gush to induce fear in the soul implanted objects, causing them to lose the implanted "soul"

Comment: _can anyone teach me how to do spoiler_ :  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72877/whats-the-exact-syntax-for-spoiler-markup

Comment: Are you confusing [Charlotte Cracker](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Charlotte_Cracker) with [Charlotte Linlin](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Charlotte_Linlin)? Because Cracker didn't eat Soru Soru no Mi but Bisu Bisu no Mi as stated on question

Comment: @Darjeeling Big Mom (Charlotte Linlin) ate Soru Soru.  She casually created the "Homies" using this ability by collecting life/soul energy and randomly dispersing it.  yolobots here is claiming that Homies are susceptible to being scared to death (because Soru Soru no Mi involves fear) and Charlotte Cracker is scary enough to cause that. I doesn't have anything to do with any powers or abilities he himself possesses.  I'm not convinced it is more than a fan theory but it isn't bad.